# Assembling a CUDA Project

Tags: cuda, extern, thrust

I have been scanning the site for questions regarding large CUDA projects and I have found some good replies, anyway I have some doubts yet.

My program, for now(it is still half-way from being complete), outputs some arrays, that are then input for Thrust library functions.

So my main doubt is:

1-Given that I am using CUDA C, I have thrust functions declared as extern "C". I was unsure of the correct way to declare those functions in the header files, and after some googling I found the following code, which I wanted to be sure is right:

```
extern "C" {
void compact(float*intxc,float*intyc,float*intzc);
void sort(float*intxc,float*intyc,float*intzc);
}
```

2- I have seen some posts here in the forum, that used "Main.cpp" as the main file, is it wrong to use a "Main.cu" file or is it indifferent?

Edit: After some thought(and advice), I really think the older questions were a bit dull.

Thanks in advance and thanks talonmies for the advice

Comment: That is four different questions, three of which are so vague that they can't be reasonably answered. I am sure you can do better than that.

Comment: The idea of the my comment was to encourage you to edit your original question to make it better, not to repeat it in comments.....

Comment: I swear that When I was writing, I was thinking of whether to edit the question or comment here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no need to declare your functions extern "C" in the most recent (post 2.3) versions of CUDA.  Besides, those functions are just C functions, they have nothing to do with CUDA.
2. You can have your main function in a .cu file or a .cpp file.  If you do the former, it must be compiled by nvcc.  If you do the latter, it should be compiled by your C++ compiler.  The file need not be named "Main".

Comment: Thank you for the reply ;). Yes I know that the file does not need to be named Main, but in my case it needs to be a .cu file, because I have CUDA kernel calls in it. Also I was using extern "C" because I thought that having C and C++ functions in the same program would cause me trouble, but I have already tested without extern and it is working